# React and Docker - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-player'

Tags: reactjs, docker

At the top of my react component (**Coffee.jsx**), I have this import:

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
```

The package 'react-player' is certainly installed, present at `package.json` and `node_modules/`.

My code runs inside a `docker` container. Everytime I spin my containers up, like so:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

I am getting this error:

```
./src/components/Coffees.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-player' in '/usr/src/app/src/components'
```

this is what console shows me:

```
Brewing.jsx:22 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-player'
    at webpackMissingModule (Brewing.jsx:22)
    at Module../src/components/Coffees.jsx (Brewing.jsx:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/App.jsx (Spotify.css:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/index.js (spotify-auth.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.0 (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

---

**docker-compose-dev.yml**:

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

**Dockerfile-dev**:

```
# base image
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

folder structure:

```
services/
       docker-compose-dev.yml
       node_modules/
       client/
             Dockerfile-dev
             package.json
             package-lock.json
             node_modules/
                         react-player/
```

---

> Temporay fix:

The hack fixing this is waiting for some time, along with some forced changes in my code either in **Coffee.jsx** or **Brewing.jsx**.

After I save the changed code, the package is found.

Then, when I stop containers and up them again, problem resumes. I have trying using the flag `--build` after `up -d`, to no avail.

Whats going on? How do I fix this?

---

> more persistent fix:

After removing volumes from docker-compose-dev.yml and rebuilding, like so:

```
#volumes:
      #- './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      #- '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

I still get the error:

```
client_1           | > client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
client_1           | > react-scripts start
client_1           | 
client_1           | Could not find a required file.
client_1           |   Name: index.html
client_1           |   Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
client_1           | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
client_1           | npm ERR! errno 1
client_1           | npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
client_1           | npm ERR! Exit status 1
client_1           | npm ERR! 
client_1           | npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
client_1           | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
client_1           | 
client_1           | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
client_1           | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-05T15_14_42_967Z-debug.log
```

Then it only works if I uncomment volumes again and run the containers with volumes. An answer explaining reasons for

a) temporary fix
b) more permanent fix

would be very appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this as "docker"; are you running this inside a Docker container?  If so, can you add the relevant `docker run` line or `docker-compose.yml` file to the question?

Comment: I sure can. please refer to edit. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing `node_modules` is such a pain with docker. There are great discussions on the stackoverflow about how you can run `Javascrip` app with docker. Here is how I do it,

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine

# first installed node_modules in cache and copy them to src folder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cache
WORKDIR /usr/src/cache

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install -q

# now make a different directory for src code 
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set path to run packages from node_modules
ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin

COPY . .
```

> docker-compose.yaml

```
app:
    build: .
    image: app
    container_name: services.app
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:5000 
    # this will copy node_modules to src folder, otherwise node_modules will be wipeed out as we don't
    # have the node_modules in the host machine
    command: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh prod
```

And my `entrypoint.sh` file looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -r /usr/src/cache/node_modules/. /usr/src/app/node_modules/

exec npm start
```

So, the basic idea here is, when you build the image you store the `node_modules` somewhere in the path, but when you actually run it, you copy that `node_modules` and place it in the app folder. This way, your local `node_modules` never clashes with the one in the docker.

You can add `node_modules` in `.dockerignore` if you want to make a `COPY` faster.

Comment: do you see why the module is found after some time and resaving the files at host? I don't understand.

Comment: It is really hard to tell without looking at the actual code and inspecting the containers at different times.Helicopter view: volume is miss behaving and the changes on any files mounting the new volume from client and you are seeing all the packages from the node_modules. Suggestion: remove volume using `docker volume prune` or with `-f` option if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First Down services:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down
```

Then re-build services (without cache):

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build --no-cache
```

In the last run services:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go for installing packages whenever container up it will install on start on stop as well plus if can control mechanism too when to install or when to go with build time modules.

```
#!/bin/sh
npm ci
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent
exec npm start
```

With this approach the container will always install updated node modules, also will not need to build each time during development.

Also, we can control this behaviour.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PACKAGE_UPDATE" = true ] ; then
    echo 'installing fresh node modules'
    # you can also remove existing modules at this step
    npm ci
    npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent
 fi
exec npm start
```

so the docker run for not installing packages will be

```
docker run -e PACKAGE_UPDATE=true -it my_image
```

and will mount the anonymous volume to not conflict with host node modules.

```
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```