# docker-compose: file shows up with ls but can't be found when executed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run a shellscript for my docker-compose frontend container. When i try to run the file I get an error suggesting that the shell file can't be found:

```
services.app | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 8: /usr/src/app/frontend/entrypoint.sh: not found
```

This is my docker-compose file:

docker-compose entry:

```
frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    image: app
    container_name: services.app
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file: ./.env
    stdin_open: true
    command: /usr/src/app/frontend/entrypoint.sh prod
```

However, when I run `command: ls /usr/src/app/frontend/` in the docker-compose file I can see the file:

```
services.app | entrypoint.sh
```

Is the shell file really missing or am I misinterpreting this error? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

edit:
the entrypoint.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -r /usr/src/cache/node_modules/. /usr/src/app/node_modules/

exec npm start
```

Comment: Did you make the shell script executable (chmod +x)?

Comment: yes it should be executable i get the following output with ls -l: `services.app | -rwxrwxr-x    1 node     node            92 Nov 21 14:55 ./frontend/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: i am running the script to get my node_modules folder as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614836/react-and-docker-uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-react-player
I will add the content of the shell script to the post

Comment: Is the file in the image?  The `volumes:` hide everything in the image, so it might not be there.  If your image is something like an Alpine-based image, it might not have a `/bin/bash` (but if `sh` works, then change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh`).  Given what you show in the script, the `node_modules` tree should be in the image, and the Dockerfile should be able to set `CMD ["npm", "start"]` without this wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can *emulate* the error, although I cannot say that's what's happening in your case:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/demo

$ ln -s /no/such/dir/entry.sh /tmp/demo/entry.sh # create soft link to non existent file

$ chmod +x /tmp/demo/entry.sh # and make it executable for good measure
```

```
$ ls /tmp/demo # so now we can list the file
entry.sh

$ /tmp/demo/entry.sh # but cannot execute it
-bash: /tmp/demo/entry.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

so what worked for me in the end was simply to append `sh` in front of the command:

```
command: sh /usr/src/app/frontend/entrypoint.sh prod
```